# Question about $\sum \frac{1}{1+(a_n)^2}$ and its properties

Tags: calculus, summation

If there is a random sum $\sum a_n$ that is absolutely convergent (so $\sum |a_n|$ converges), would $\sum \frac{1}{1+(a_n)^2}$ converge as well?

---

Presently I have no clue how this is supposed to work, but I got some ideas. Since this is any $a_n$ that is absolutely convergent, then it is also convergent in general. If it's convergent, then it cannot be something like $2^n$ or $n^4$ and the like. So if you reciprocate it (put a fraction on it) then it most likely converges too.

Comment: Consider $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$, then $\frac{1}{1+a_n^2}\nrightarrow 0$

Comment: The terms of a convergent series must go to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.  But if $a_n$ goes to $0$, $1/(1+a_n^2)$ goes to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that $\sum \frac 1 {1 + a_n^2}$ will never converge.

The reason is that, for a series $\sum x_n$ to converge, whether absolutely or not, a necessary condition is that the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n$ is $0$.

Now if $\lim a_n$ is zero, then we would have $\lim \frac 1 {1 + a_n^2} = 1$ and hence $\sum \frac 1 {1 + a_n^2}$ doesn't converge.